# Passing Data from parent view to child view in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, data-manipulation

I have a view which contains a mat table with user data in the parent view on selecting an entry in the table I want to be able to open a new view with the selected row data pre populated.

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="registeredUsersDataSource" matSort>

        <!-- First Name Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
          <mat-header-cell class="columnHeadingText" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> First Name
          </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell class="columnCellText" *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.firstName}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Last Name Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="lastName">
          <mat-header-cell class="columnHeadingText" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Last Name </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell class="columnCellText" *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.lastName}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- E-mail Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="emailId">
          <mat-header-cell class="columnHeadingText" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> E-mail </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell class="columnCellText" *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.emailId}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Country Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="country">
          <mat-header-cell class="columnHeadingText interCellPadding" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Country
          </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell class="columnCellText interCellPadding" *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.country |
            codeToCountryConversion}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Role Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="role">
          <mat-header-cell class="columnHeadingText" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Roles </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell class="columnCellText" *matCellDef="let row">
            <label *ngIf='row.rolesAccess[0]' class="columnCellText ">{{row.rolesAccess[0].role ===
              'API_ApplicationDeveloper' ? 'Developer' : row.rolesAccess[0].role }}</label> <br>
            <label *ngIf='row.rolesAccess[1]' class="columnCellText ">{{row.rolesAccess[1].role ===
              'API_ApplicationDeveloper' ? 'Developer' : row.rolesAccess[1].role }}</label> <br>
            <label *ngIf='row.rolesAccess[2]' class="columnCellText ">{{row.rolesAccess[2].role ===
              'API_ApplicationDeveloper' ? 'Developer' : row.rolesAccess[2].role }}</label>
          </mat-cell>

          <!-- <label *ngIf='{{row.rolesAccess[1].role}}' class="columnCellText ">{{row.rolesAccess[1].role}}</label>
              <label *ngIf='{{row.rolesAccess[2].role}}'class="columnCellText ">{{row.rolesAccess[2].role}}</label> </mat-cell>    -->
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Action Buttons Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
          <mat-header-cell class="columnHeadingText" *matHeaderCellDef> Actions </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell class="columnCellText" *matCellDef="let row">

            <!-- Edit User -->
            <button title="Edit User" appDtsButton class="btnNoBorder" (click)="onClickRegisteredUsersEdit(row)">
              <sap-icon [iconName]="'sap-icon://edit'"></sap-icon>

              <!-- Used to pass row data into to view -->
              <app-edituser hidden="true" [value]='sujith'>
              </app-edituser>

            </button>

            <!-- Revoke User -->
            <button title="Revoke User" appDtsButton class="btnNoBorder" (click)="onClickRegisteredUsersRevoke(row)">
              <sap-icon [iconName]="'sap-icon://cancel'"></sap-icon>
            </button>
          </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="registeredUsersDisplayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: registeredUsersDisplayedColumns;">
        </mat-row>
      </mat-table>
```

This is the code I have in the child view to recieve the data and print it.

```
export class EdituserComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() value: string;

ngOnInit() {
console.log(this.value);
```

}

When I try to print it out i get undefined.

Ideally I want to be able to pass an object into the second view with all the details of the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here -

> 1. Passing the @Input value

```
 <app-edituser hidden="true" [value]="'sujith'">
```

> 2. The place where are you accessing the input value.

Its not necessary that you will be having the @Input value in `ngOnInit` method. You should look for @Input once the view is ready. So you can get it in in `ngAfterViewInit` function

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   console.log(this.value);
}
```

Comment: `@Input` should be checked in `ngOnInit`, why it should be checked in `ngAfterViewInit` if it doesn't related to view ?

Comment: The docs state `ngOnInit` is called "after Angular first [...] sets the directive/component's input properties."

Comment: Artyom and user184994 - I agree with you guys with the current case since the value is hard coded however there are many cases where the values comes from API or other async cases where the value passed is not necessary that it is available in ngOnInit function.

Comment: If it comes from an async source, then there is no guarantee it will be there in `ngAfterViewInit` either?

Comment: The code works in the ngAfterViewInit(). I am able to print out sujith on the console.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `[]` syntax, it will try to parse the value. In this example:

```
[value]='sujith'
```

Is looking for a variable called `sujith`.

Instead, you can either do

```
[value]='"sujith"'
```

Or

```
value='sujith'
```

Comment: @user184994 Unfortunate this is not working :(. Can u help me with a better way to pass data between views.

Comment: That is the best way of passing data to be honest. Can you create a StackBlitz that reproduces the issue? I can't see why it wouldn't be working...